whereType<Folder> is not recognized
I would like to list all folders using Flutter and Dart.
I need to create a list and determine whether a list item is a file or a folder.
For some reason, whereType<Folder>() is not recognized.
Could you please advise how to address the issue.
Thank You,
here is my code:
Directory dir = Directory('C:/test');
final List explorerList = dir.listSync().toList();
final List<Folder> folders = explorerList.whereType<Folder>();


In any case, whereType returns an Iterable, not a List. You would need to call explorerList.whereType<Folder>().toList();
